# admob in adobe phonegap build service

Tags: admob, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK to creat a Jquery mobile app. I added an admob plugin by following this instruction (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/wiki/02.-How-to-Use-with-Intel-XDK) to my app in Intel XDK. I tested the app on an android emulator which is 4.3.1 with API level 18. The admob is shown well on the emulator. Then, I used the Adobe Phonegap Build service to package my app to an apk file and installed it in my android phone. However, the admob didn't work on my phone. I tested a couple of Jquery mobile apps both on the emulator and mobile phone. The result is same: they all work on the emulator but not on my mobile phone. I googled a bit found some posts suggesting Phonegap Build don't support admob well. So, I suspect that the reason why admob is not shown on my phone is I used Phonegap Build Service to package my app and Phonegap Build don't support admob. Can somebody please tell me if Phonegap Builde Servie support admob? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To use in phone gap build you should place this tag in config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks a lot for the reply. I am going to add this line to my index.html and test it again on my phone.

Comment: That line needs to go into your config.xml, not your index.html file. Did you try using the XDK build service?

Comment: Hi xmnboy, I've tried the above line of code in config.xml, but it did't work on my mobile. In XDK, this file is called "intelxdk.config.android.xml". I only used the XDK build service to test it on my emulator. I used Phonegap build service instead the XDK build service to test it on my mobile because it is easier to install it on my mobile using a QR code scanner. I really can't figure out what's wrong in my app. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After a couple of times testing both on emulator and real device, I think for XDK Jquery mobile app with admob integrated, if the apk file is built in XDK build service, the admob will work; if the apk file is built in Phonegap build service, the admob will not work. So, Phonegap build doesn't support admob integraged in XDK jquery mobile app.